# Exclude field from `dataclass.astuple`

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Is there a way to exclude a field from being returned by `dataclass.astuple`?

For example:

```
    @dataclass
    class Test:
        int_field: int
        string_field: str
        list_field: list
```

You can use `astuple` to write to the database but `list_field` should be excluded since it would be written in a different manner.

Comment: there are one or two ways. if you can explain real quick why you need it to be excluded, I could try to write an answer.

Comment: Writing to DB for example.

Comment: and why don't you want `list_field` to be written to DB? because writing lists to DBs is bad practice?

Comment: @Arne I do.  But in order to save a list of objects in a database you either turn it into a single object like a comma delimited string or you have it in another table.  So if you want to save `Test` object in a test table you save the list in another table associating a key from the `Test` table in order to be able to reassemble the object.  Or you save it as a JSON object which for other reasons you may not want to do.

Comment: You would have to write your own function. `dataclass.astuple` gets the fields from the `dataclasses.fields` function, so you would have to remove it as a field to exclude it.